# Pandas merging rows

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have imported a csv file in jupyter panda with a data structure like this:

```
Handle  | Name | Vendor| Option1 Name | Option1 Value |

drive-gt| Aero | Bando | Size         |               |
drive-gt|      |       |              | S             |
drive-gt|      |       |              | M             |
drive-gt|      |       |              | XL            |
drive-gt|      |       |              | XXL           |
```

There are more than 1000 different handles. I would like to put the Option1 Value of each 2nd handle-row in the 1st row and then delete the 2nd row. So like this:

```
Handle  | Name | Vendor| Option1 Name | Option1 Value |

drive-gt| Aero | Bando | Size         | S             |
drive-gt|      |       |              | M             |
drive-gt|      |       |              | XL            |
drive-gt|      |       |              | XXL           |
```

Any ideas how to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: unstack rows into new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62515867/pandas-unstack-rows-into-new-columns)

Comment: @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism not really. What I want to do is to loop throught all my handles. And where handles are similar merge the 1st and 2nd row.

Comment: could you show how your output should be like?

Comment: @ricky I edited my question with the desired output per unique handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the test DataFrame contains data for 2 handles, with "empty" cells
containing just an empty string (not *NaN*, as in your data sample):

```
     Handle  Name Vendor Option1 Name Option1 Value
0  drive-gt  Aero  Bando         Size              
1  drive-gt                                       S
2  drive-gt                                       M
3  drive-gt                                      XL
4  drive-gt                                     XXL
5     abcde  Xxxx  Yyyyy        Width              
6     abcde                                       A
7     abcde                                       B
8     abcde                                       C
```

I see that you have your data properly sorted, so the most intuitive solution is to:

- group rows by *Handle*,
- then in each group:

  - copy the original group to a new variable, to avoid warnings
    concerning overwriting of the "original" data (at the later step),
  - copy data from the first row to the second, in columns 1, 2 and 3 only,
  - return the current group, but starting from the **second** row.

The code to do it is:

1. Define a function to "reformat" the current group:

   ```
    def myReformat(grp):
        rv = grp.copy()
        rv.iloc[1, 1:4] = rv.iloc[0, 1:4]
        return rv.iloc[1:]
   ```
2. Apply it to each group:

   ```
    result = df.groupby('Handle', sort=False).apply(myReformat).reset_index(drop=True)
   ```

   The final *reset_index* is needed to delete an additional index level
   introduced by *groupby*. Actually it would be sufficient to drop only
   level *0* of the MultiIndex, but I thought that a better choice is
   to drop also the second ("original") level of the MultiIndex and
   recreate the new index as a **continuous** sequence of integers.

The result, for the above data is:

```
     Handle  Name Vendor Option1 Name Option1 Value
0  drive-gt  Aero  Bando         Size             S
1  drive-gt                                       M
2  drive-gt                                      XL
3  drive-gt                                     XXL
4     abcde  Xxxx  Yyyyy        Width             A
5     abcde                                       B
6     abcde                                       C
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Handle':['drive-gt','drive-gt','drive-gt','drive-gt','drive-gt','drive-gt1','drive-gt1','drive-gt1','drive-gt1','drive-gt1'],
    'Name':['Aero','','','','','Aero','','','',''],
    'Vendor':['Bando','','','','','Bando','','','',''],
    'Option1 Name':['Size','','','','','Size','','','',''],
    'Option1 Value':['','S','M','XL','XXL','','S','M','XL','XXL']
})

    

#import numpy
import numpy as np
#replace all space by nan
df=df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
#ffill for each group
df=df.groupby('Handle').ffill()
#remove all Option1 Value which are nan
df=df[~df['Option1 Value'].isnull()]
```